# Dynamic content selection not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.lst', function (e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 13) {
        html = '<tr>';
        html += '<td>' + i + '</td>';
        html += '<td><select class="inputs form-control selectpicker prd" data-live-search="true" name="code_' + i + '" id="code_' + i + '"></select></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" class="inputs form-control" name="price_' + i + '" id="price_' + i + '" /></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" class="inputs form-control" name="qty_' + i + '" id="qty_' + i + '" /></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" class="inputs form-control" name="disc_' + i + '" id="disc_' + i + '" /></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" class="inputs form-control" name="tax_' + i + '" id="tax_' + i + '" /></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" class="inputs form-control lst" name="total_' + i + '" id="total_' + i + '" /></td>';
        html += '</tr>';
        $('table').append(html);

             $.ajax({    
                            type: "post",
                            url: "pages/get_products.php", 
                            data: html,
                            dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
                            success: function(response){                    
                                $('#code_' + i).html(response); 
                            }
                    });

        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({ size: 4});
        $('.selectpicker').focus().select();
        i++;
    }
});
```

**get_products.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
require "../model/configuration.php";
?>
<?php
$queryprd=$db->execute("select * from product_add where delet='0'");
while($result=$queryprd->fetch_assoc())
{
?>
<option value="<?php echo $result['productcode']."|".$result['productname'];?>"><?php echo $result['productcode']."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$result['productname'];?></option>
<?php
}
?>
```

For first row dynamic selection working properly, here we use enter key to focus on next input field. while we pressing **enter key** on last input field it create new row. we facing problem in newly created row , the select option on the second row is not working ,and we can't select the product list. please help us to resolve this issue  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the lines:

```
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({ size: 4});
  $('.selectpicker').focus().select();
  i++;
```

Inside the AJAX success function and change the '`.selectpicker`' for '`#code_'+i .selectpicker`

Usually you have to add the selector parameter, otherwise the event is directly bound instead of delegated, which only works if the element already exists (so it doesn't work for dynamically loaded content).

See http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

like: `.on("click", function(event){`

But with `selectpicker()` I think that it couldn't be done.

You have the option: `.selectpicker('refresh');`

> //This is necessary when removing or adding options, or when
>   disabling/enabling a select via JavaScript.

UPDATE

Acording to your demo, you should use:

```
$('#code_'+i).sibiling('.inputs').find('.selecticker').html(response);
```

Because in there is a dynamic created content by `selectpicker`. You have to attach the data to the proper element (`<ul class='selectpicker...'></ul>`).

For that, you need to first create de `selectpicker` by using:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({ size: 4});
$('.selectpicker').focus().select();
i++;
```

And then attach the content in it and then update the pickers:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Comment: $('#code_'+i +'.selectpicker').selectpicker({ size: 4});<br>
$('#code_'+i +'.selectpicker').focus().select();<br>
i++;<br>

Comment: `$('#code_'+i+'.selectpicker').selectpicker`and then you can also do this:
`$('#code_'+i+'.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh'); $('#code_'+i+'.selectpicker').selectpicker('render');` Hope it helps.

Comment: check this demo http://oliviaholylandtours.com/demo/ press enter key to each input fields

Comment: The selectpicker is working but the options are not loaded, right?

Comment: ya, its my problem